# What's the code for htaccess in my case?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The previous less described question has removed.

Specified question:

• The question have described in the statement. Please read at-least once..

• My goal is to have friendly url. So I do some actions..

1. it simply works with:    ^thread/[(0-9)+]/(*?) $thread.php?id=$1
2. but not working with this:    ^thread/[(0-9)+]/page/[(0-9)+]/(*?) $thread.php?id=$1&page=$2

i discovered changing 'thread' (for 2)  into another word like..

1. ^anotherWord/[(0-9)+]/page/[(0-9)+]/(*?)
   $thread.php?id=$1&page=2

(above) is working fine..
but many of you are doing such..

I mean, you have

```
blog/id/1/blog-title.html    
blog/id/1/page/2/blog-title.html    
blog/edit/id/1
```

all for your blog.php

```
blog.php?id=1    
blog.php?id=1&page=2    
blog.php?id=1&edit
```

Here, id, page and blog-title can have any value. Actually id and page is a $_GET var. with this id i can pull out the blog title from db.

So what to do to get working friendly url? Please reply me..

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^forum/(\d+)/response/[^/]*$ post.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(thread|forum)/(\d+)(?:/page/(\d+))?/[^/]*$ $1.php?id=$2&page=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: i have tryied but its not working..
one thing is that the id and page no will auto. generated.

Comment: @FarhanIhsas Update your question with what you mean by auto generated. Why did you think it was not important to share that before? It becomes easier to understand and solve a problem if we have all the details beforehand.

Comment: sorry, i assumed you will get it..usually its a php script, so its a get var, which can be changed..Anyway, really sorry. I have updated the question to understand easily. Thanks for replying. Please help me.

Comment: @FarhanIhsas Please, check my update. This should work as per the new details added to the question.